# Merge from other fork

Tags: git, git-merge

I've forked a repository, and made some changes. Now, the repository I originally forked has had updates, and I want to make some more changes and put in a pull request. My question is, how can I merge what I've done so far with the original repo that I forked?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally add the original repository as another remote, so I can pull in changes easily.

For example, say I forked the node.js express project: expressjs/express -> sankethkatta/express. I would do:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:sankethkatta/express.git
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com:expressjs/express.git
```

Now when I need to pull in changes, I simply do:

```
$ git pull upstream master
```